# Running tests from Android Studio IDE doesn't rebuild pure java library module

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, junit, kotlin

I have a project in Android Studio which only has a single non-android, pure java module. This module contains a class which I put under test.

The test is executed properly if I manually call `gradle build` or `gradle test`.

But if I run it from the IDE ("Run 'All tests'"), the module is not rebuild, it is run on old compiled code. Only when I rebuild it manually with e.g. `gradle compileTestJava` the code is recompiled and tests are executed properly.

It seems similar to this problem: [Android Studio doesn't compile test classes for Java library modules during Make Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42526584/android-studio-doesnt-compile-test-classes-for-java-library-modules-during-make)

Comment: This was a bug in the build tool, and fixed in 3.0 Canary 9. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64047846 What version of the build tools are you using?

Comment: I use AS2 with build tools 2.3.3. I have even more problems with building pure java module now after restart. So using AS3 may help?

Comment: Installed Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2 with 2.3.3 build tools and unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: back in 3.3.0 and 3.3.1, it seems.

Comment: back in 3.6.1 as well